where to enable the camera, move view, zoom view, perspective/ortographic icons on 3d viewport in Blender 3.6
I'm using blender on a keyboard without the numpad and I have been looking for ages on how to enable the camera, move view, zoom view, perspective/ortographic icons on 3d viewport in Blender 3.6.

I cant find it on show overlays / show gizmos options on 3d viewport nor in the navigation options on blender's preferences.
Anyone knows how can I enable it in Blender 3.6?
Could anyone help me with this please?

Try hitting Ctrl-` (backquote) - the key below Esc on UK keyboards or clicking the Viewport Gizmos icon on the top toolbar.

unfortunately it only shows and hides the current configuration of viewport's gizmos and won't turn on the navigation icons that I need

There's also an entry under Edit > Preferences Interface > Editors > Navigation Controls which will turn the Zoom, Move, Camera and Current View icons on and off if it's just those ones you need.

that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Ah good! I've no idea why it was considered necessary to put setting for that in two different places! I didn't realise the Preferences one was there until I looked for it. Normally it's checked by default. :^)

Now added as an answer...

After some searching it turns out that there's a setting to enable and disable visibility of those controls under Edit > Preferences > Interface > Editors > Navigation Controls.

